# Error while installing C++ Redistributable 2015 on the Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, 64-bit

I need to install **MySQL** and **WorkBench tool** on the Windows Server 2012 R2. As the prerequesites it needs **Visual C++ Redistributable 2015** So I downloaded and tried to install but getting below error:

Log details:

> [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:20]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:20]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:20]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:20]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:20]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:20]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:20]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:20]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:20]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:20]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:20]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:20]i300: Apply begin
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:22]w308: Automatic updates could not be paused due to error: 0x80240025. Continuing...
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:22]i360: Creating a system restore point.
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:22]i362: System restore disabled, system restore point not created.
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:22]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:22]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1.JAI\AppData\Local\Temp\3{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}.be\VC_redist.x64.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, version: 14.0.23026.0
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
>   [1FD4:0E1C][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.
>   [1FD4:0E1C][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi.
>   [1FD4:0E1C][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i304: Verified existing payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503.
>   [1FD4:0E1C][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\cab1.cab.
>   [1FD4:0E1C][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.
>   [1FD4:0E1C][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi.
>   [1FD4:0E1C][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i304: Verified existing payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92.
>   [1FD4:0E1C][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\cab1.cab.
>   [1FD4:0E1C][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i304: Verified existing payload: Windows81_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\Windows81_x64.
>   [1FD4:0E1C][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i305: Verified acquired payload: Windows81_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\Windows81_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\FC6260C33678BB17FB8B88536C476B4015B7C5E9\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i325: Registering dependency: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:24]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:25]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:25]i325: Registering dependency: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:25]i301: Applying execute package: Windows81_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\FC6260C33678BB17FB8B88536C476B4015B7C5E9\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\FC6260C33678BB17FB8B88536C476B4015B7C5E9\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart'
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:26]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:26]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:26]i319: Applied execute package: Windows81_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:26]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:26]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
>   [1FD4:1FC0][2019-11-29T00:24:26]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
>   [1B20:0F78][2019-11-29T00:24:26]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No

- OS: Windows Server R2
- System Type: 64 bit OS, x64-based processor
- Updated: Yes
- MySQL Version: 5.5
- WorkBench Version: 8.0.18

What I tried:

Downloaded update package from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49063) but getting an error while installing:

> This update is not applicable for your computer

Installed Updates (Screenshot):

[image]

What could the reason behind this?

I really new to this kind of stuff, please help!

Comment: There are two likely reasons why [KB2999226](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) isn't applicable: either it is already installed, or your machine is too out of date to install it.  Start by checking the "installed updates" in Programs and Features.  Checking Windows Update might also be helpful.

Comment: Give me a minute, checking

Comment: @HarryJohnston The windows update is already done and as per list its showing latest `KB2975061`

Comment: I am using license product key, is that will be a problem? I am really new to this, please help!

Comment: @HarryJohnston Have edited question with Installed Updates SS please check and guide!

Comment: Is your .MSI the x86 version ? as 2012-r2 need an 64 bit version. (Your error log show the x86 filename)

Comment: @yagmoth555-GoFundMeMonica Yes I tried with both in - for x86 showing system compatability error and x64 shows `This update is not applicable for your computer`

Comment: @yagmoth555-GoFundMeMonica Check the updated logs - its getting when I installing MS C++ redistribuable 2015 on my Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: @HarryJohnston Saw screenshot?

Comment: @yagmoth555-GoFundMeMonica need you advice!

Comment: The screenshot isn't much help because it only shows part of the list.  Is KB4525243 on the list?  When you do a Windows Update scan does it offer any additional updates?

Comment: @HarryJohnston i will check n let you know

Comment: @HarryJohnston You are genius! Just restarted server -> Check for updates -> Its showed me one important update -> Updated and `vc_redist.x64` successfully installed -> Then workbench is also installed n happy to see database live.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Please post an answer, will help someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various reasons why you might get the *this update is not applicable for your computer* message.

- The update is mismatched to the version of Windows or the computer architecture, e.g., attempting to install a Windows 7 update on Windows 10 or a 32-bit update on 64-bit Windows.  Check this first, because it is easy.
- The update is already installed, or a later update that supersedes the update is installed.
- You don't have the indicated prerequisites; or
- Your machine is too out of date.

Those last two are the same thing really, but sometimes the prerequisites for an update aren't explicitly listed or when you try to install them you run into the same problem again; if there is a tree of prerequisites it can be a lot of work to get them all installed by hand.  So, unless you are [trying to do an offline update](https://serverfault.com/q/979174/94065), it is usually preferable to bring your machine completely up to date with Windows Update before doing any further troubleshooting.

To make sure of this, run a Windows Update scan, *even if the Windows Update control panel tells you you are up to date*, and install any updates offered.  Reboot and repeat.  Note that after updates are installed, the Windows Update client will not always show you all of the follow-up updates that may now be applicable, that's why you need to explicitly ask it to do a scan.